# What could this error be?

Tags: php, apache

I have upgraded PHP from 5.4 to 5.6 on one of our local servers, and now I have a php file, which when I try to open from the browser, it only results in a blank white screen.

The error reporting in `php.ini` is set to on, and I've also told at the beginning of the file to report all errors, yet the output is still blank. When I checked the error_log, it is empty. If I delete the whole content of the .php file, and replace it with a simple echo, everything works perfectly.

How could I debug this error?

Comment: can you please paste .php file contents

Comment: It would be really hard, because multiple files are included. I've managed to pin down the stop of the script, to an invalid require statement, the question is now, why isn't php reporting this error to me?

Comment: Try error_reporting(-1); // show all
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Try this and see if it's working properly.

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @brslv that solved it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** Your **`error_reporting`** function may be off in your `php.ini` file.

**Solution :**
Sometimes by default in `php.ini` the display error function is off or allowed to show limited errors.

**DISPLAY ERROR'S IN YOUR PHP FILE :**

So to enable displaying errors in your `php` file,You will need to add one of the following statements at the begining of your php file  just right after your `<?php` starting tag.

**Note :** By using any one of these statements,your php file will show every possible error.!

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

**Reference Links :**

- > http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors
- > http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors
- > http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

**@Credit Goes To @[brslv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6324435/brslv)**